# How to compile my own ’***.so‘ and '***.jar' in ASOP? so that to let it be android system api?

Tags: java, android

I have some '***.so' and '***.jar' files,and I want to make it be android system api.But I don`t know how to add it to AOSP to let it be android system api?

Comment: You question is too vague. By talking the 'android system api', do you mean the usual API in SDK?

Comment: @ reavenisadesk.Yes. I mean I want to customized AOSP,and I have already compiled  android 5.0 successfully. And then I have some third  `***.so`and`***.jar` file,I want to compile them in AOSP  so that   all app can use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is complicated.

First you should implement a new system service in framework/base/service to call the method in your jar. Then modify Android.mk in the framework/base/service to make sure you jar will be compiled into your build.

Then make sure your service is allowed to access resources by registering the service to Linux-SE system.

Then implement a manager class and an AIDL in framework/base/core to make sure your manager service will be able to communicate to your service. Register your AIDL in framework/base/core/Android.mk.

Finally since you changed the default system API, you should use command `make update-api` to update your API.

This just a brief introduction, every step has traps. Doing what you want requires fully acknowledge to AOSP build system and AOSP framework, if you are a beginner of AOSP, there's a lot to learn before action.

Comment: I am confused about it. Some says we can put the jar file in framework,and write an Android.mk like this:LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
 
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c
 include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: Sorry. what i say up is wrong

Comment: That's the way to add the library into you build, it neither a system API nor will be used by anyone.